# Procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have been created small student page, I added dropdown list for extracurricular.

So that I did the following:

1. First create table name Ecurricular
2. Insert lots of curricular activities in the table Ecurricular.
3. Create storedprocedure sp_insertextracurricular

and here is the [screenshot](http://s30.postimg.org/gd0jn7wwx/untitled.jpg) table data from Ecurricular table

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_insertextracurricular", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", extracurricular.Text.Trim());
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@extracurricular", Textcurricular.Text.Trim());

    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        extracurricular.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["id"].ToString();
        Textcurricular.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["extracurricular"].ToString();
    }
}
```

ASPX markup:

```
<td><asp:HiddenField ID="curricular" runat="server" /> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="extracurricular" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="Textcurricular" runat="server" BackColor="#FF0066" 
                Height="16px" Width="129px"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_insertextracurricular
AS
begin
     select * 
     from Ecurricular
End
```

When I run this above code I get an error

> Procedure sp_insertextracurricular has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

I'm new to .net., I need to display Ecurricular data on dropdown list, I just confused with this, may I know what is my mistake in my code?

Comment: Well yes - look at your `sp_insertextracurricular` stored proc - it doesn't have any parameters. You're trying to specify `@id` and `@extracurricular`... what do you expect those to do? (It's also really confusing to have a stored procedure with a name which sounds like it will do an insert, but actually just runs a query...)

Comment: Small semantic point: Don't name your stored procedure `insertXXX` if it's selecting data - that will be very confusing. It should probably be named `getXXX` ot `selectXXX`.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Than you for your comment @jon skeet..

Comment: Thank you for your comment @jameic...

Answer (score 1):

You've added the parameters `@id` and `@extracurricular` but haven't included them in the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_insertextracurricular
AS
begin
select * from Ecurricular
End
```

You need to add them like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_insertextracurricular
    @id varchar(10),
    @extracurricular varchar(200)
AS
begin
select * from Ecurricular
End
```

I'm guessing at the column sizes/datatypes here, you'll want to review these.

Comment: @Rani What does that have to do with this question?

Comment: I need to display that table data values like 'speech,painting....' in dropdown list in front end..

Comment: @Rani Submit a new question, that's an unrelated problem.

Comment: @Rani You mentioned it as the *end goal* but that isn't the crux of your problem is it? `Procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied in c#` - read your own title. You haven't even shared any code on how you're binding the values to the dropdown list, how can you expect someone to answer a question which you have not asked?

Answer (score -1):

This is not a .NET problem. The stored procedure you provided doesn't take ANY parameters but you are creating parmeters here and passing them in.

```
   com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", extracurricular.Text.Trim());
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@extracurricular", Textcurricular.Text.Trim());
```

The error is telling you not to pass anything as the stored procedure doesn't take any.

You will need to update your stored procedure to take those values since it looks like you are eventually going to turn it into an insert.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_insertextracurricular
   @id VARCHAR, --<---looks like you are passing a string, make sure to make this what it actually needs to be
   @extracurricular VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
select * from Ecurricular --<---I take it this will become and insert based on Stored Procedure name.
End
```

Comment: Neat I got a -2 for a similar answer at the same time as the one that got +2.